# problema con input type checkbox con id repetidos (javascript / jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

Tengo un formulario en el cual por cada plato se puede seleccionar (checkbox) adicionales como algarrobina,maca,etc. Y todos estos se repiden por cada plato, es decir cada plato tiene su propia lista igual pero independiente de checkbox
plato 1 => algarrobina,maca,etc
plato 2 => algarrobina,maca,etc

Lo hago asi porque al procesar el pedido recorro todos los checkbox marcados y lo adjunto al plato (tema aparte).

Mi problema esta en que el primer div me detecta los checkbox con normalidad, es el los siguientes div donde al dar click en un checkbox no me lo marca (css/html) ya que detecta el checkbox primero con el mismo id y ese si lo marca, es decir si yo marco cualquier checkbox con id = 1 me va a marcar no el actual si no el primer checkbox con id = 1;

```html
<tr><td>
<select><option>plato1</option><option>plato2</option></select>
<div>
<input type="checkbox" id="1"><label for="1">hola</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="2"><label for="2">hola</label>
</div>
</td>
</tr>

<tr><td>
<select><option>plato1</option><option>plato2</option></select>
<div>
<input type="checkbox" id="1"><label for="1">hola</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="2"><label for="2">hola</label>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
```

Obviamente el problema es que los id de los checkbox se repiten, pero yo digo, ahy alguna forma de usar checkbox sin id ?

Notas:

1. uso este metodo de repetir el div con los checkbox por plato ya que lo muestro y oculto con un modal y si se equivocan en elegir un check pueden volver a abrir el cotnenedor y editar
2. mi checkbox usa css en el cual me exige que exista un label
3. es posible crear un plato nuevo con su respectivo contenedor de check (dinamicamente)

Comment: Ten en cuenta que los ids se suponen deben ser únicos

Comment: claro si amigo, pero el problema es que para que un label funcione tiene que estar "conectado" con el el id del checkbox

Comment: Si, pues lo que puedes hacer es cambiar el ID de los checkbox y que sea algo cómo plato-{i}-1 y plato-{i}-2, donde {i} se reemplaza por el índice de cada plato. Y así todos los ids son únicos

Comment: la cosa es que tambien creo estos checkbox de manera dinamica,

Comment: Puedes  poner el  javascript, por favor.

Comment: como te digo amigo esto va por un tema de html mas que por javascript, mi javascript detecta los checkbox activos pero no logro activarlos

Answer (score 0):

De entrada, tu enfoque no es correcto, porque los [ID deben ser únicos](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id) y no deben ser numéricos:

> Nota: El uso de caracteres a excepción de letras en ASCII, dígitos, '_', '-' y '.' pueden ocasionar problemas de compatibilidad, por no ser permitidos en HTML 4. A pesar de que esta limitación ha sido removida en HTML 5, **un ID debe iniciar con una letra para asegurar la compatibilidad**.

Además, todos deberían tener un nombre asignado, de lo contrario, se va a complicar innecesariamente el envío de formularios, dependiendo 100% de javascript, agregando manualmente cada campo, sin posibilidad de `new FormData(formulario)`.

Para que las etiquetas activen el *checkbox* correspondiente, evita usar el atributo `for` (porque sabes que los ID están repetidos) y coloca el *checkbox* dentro de la etiqueta.

```html
<table>
<tr>
    <td>
        <select>
            <option>plato1</option>
            <option>plato2</option>
        </select>
        <div>
            <label><input type="checkbox" id="1"> hola</label>
            <label><input type="checkbox" id="2"> hola</label>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <select>
            <option>plato1</option>
            <option>plato2</option>
        </select>
        <div>
            <label><input type="checkbox" id="1"> hola</label>
            <label><input type="checkbox" id="2"> hola</label>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Para cumplir con el punto 2 de tu pregunta:

> Mi *checkbox* usa CSS, en el cual me exige que exista un label

Probablemente una aproximación más adecuada sea asignar ID a las filas y usarlo también para los campos. No es lo óptimo, pero ya tienes un HTML correcto y puedes acceder fácilmente a cada fila y sus elementos:

```js
// Como ejemplo, escuchar cambios en selects
document.querySelectorAll('table select').forEach(sel => {
    sel.addEventListener('change', getRow);
});
// También escuchar cambios en checkboxes
document.querySelectorAll('table input[type="checkbox"]').forEach(chk => {
    chk.addEventListener('change', getRow);
});


function getRow(e) {
    // Obtener fila
    let tr = e.target.closest('tr');
    // Separar ID para obtener número
    let id = tr.id.split('-').pop();
    console.log(id);
    // Ya se puede acceder a otros elementos
    // Valor del select:
    console.log(tr.querySelector(`#select-${id}`).value);
    // Checkboxes
    console.log(tr.querySelector(`#chk-${id}-1`).checked);
    console.log(tr.querySelector(`#chk-${id}-2`).checked);
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr id="tr-1">
    <td>
        <select id="select-1">
            <option>plato1</option>
            <option>plato2</option>
        </select>
        <div>
            <input type="checkbox" id="chk-1-1"> <label for="chk-1-1">hola</label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="chk-1-2"> <label for="chk-1-2">hola</label>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr id="tr-2">
    <td>
        <select id="select-2">
            <option>plato1</option>
            <option>plato2</option>
        </select>
        <div>
            <input type="checkbox" id="chk-2-1"> <label for="chk-2-1">hola</label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="chk-2-2"> <label for="chk-2-2">hola</label>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```